# Adding additional contraints when defining an eloquent relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-8

Is there a way to use additional conditions when defining an eloquent relationship in a model?

Let's say I have:

```
public function researchtopic() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ResearchTopic', 'taggable_id');
}
```

But I want to add an additional where condition to use a 2nd column in the relationship as well.

How would I add a 2nd condition for:

> WHERE taggable_type = "ResearchTopic"

Comment: where 'type'? or where 'taggable_type'?

Comment: Just in general, but this particular time it's "WHERE taggable_type = 'ResearchTopic'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the "where" method directly after the belongsTo argument, or use laravel Scope to add conditions for the relation :

```
public function researchtopic() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ResearchTopic', 'taggable_id')->where('taggable_type', 'ResearchTopic');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes